# How to use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab in Manifest V3

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I try to update Manifest Version from 2 to 3.
And chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab throw error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Either the '<all_urls>' or 'activeTab' permission is required.
```

As '<all_urls>' is not available in Manifest 3, I declared the 'activeTab' permission. But it doesn't work.

As My code in Background.ts

```js
export const getCapture = (): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab((dataUrl) => resolve(dataUrl));
  });
};
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  ...,
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
}
```

So how can I use this api to take a screenshot in Manifest 3? Or should I use another api?

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab:

1. declare '<all-urls>' permission but it was abandon in Manifest V3.
2. declare 'activeTabs' permission. But it only work when the user invokes the extension as [Chrome Extension Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/) mentioned. So if you use chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab directly, it throw error.

Comment: `<all_urls>` is available in MV3. It should be declared in `host_permissions`. See the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).